# Brillig! Another riddle!

Tags: riddle

A nice easy riddle to start the day with.

```
I'm a slap from a tasty fish!
I make a wholesome sausage sandwich.
You'll find me in a ship, 
washing a pig to the tune of a flower and a rooster!
```

**What am I?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is it

> Talking nonsense/garbage?

Because:

I'm a slap from a tasty fish!

> Codswallop

I make a wholesome sausage sandwich.

> Porker pies/porkies? Or maybe baloney?

You'll find me in a ship,

> ?

washing a pig

> Hogwash

to the tune of a flower and a rooster!

> Poppycock

Comment: I didn't want it to be THAT easy.  Talk about quick.  +1  The one you missed was "Bilge".

Comment: Also I assume that "brillig" hints at the Jabberwocky poem.

Comment: @MartinEnder Lewis Carroll and his nonsense verse  :)  +1

Comment: Even after reading accepted answer, I still have no idea what this is about. Maybe care to explain more or the context?

Comment: These are slightly older English terms for saying something was nonsense, i.e "That was pure poppycock" as in "That was rubbish", or "Hogswash!" as in "Nonsense!"

Comment: When I read the first spoiler, before reading the others, I thought this was going to be a joke answer.